# npm dependencies not updating in Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have updated my package.json in my Angular SPA .Net Core Template.

I have then right clicked on the package.json file and selected 'restore packages'.

(I get the message installing packages and then installing packages completed in the bottom left hand corner of the program with no errors).

However, when I view the dependencies under the solution explorer they are still showing the old versions? (see the picture below);

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone tell me how I can get the npm in the list to match please?

Answer (score 4):

Go into cmd (preferably as administrator), navigate to the folder containing the package.json, then run npm install.

If you dont see packages updating, check for a package-lock.json file in either the same folder or one folder up and delete it. Retry running the npm install again and it should work.

Comment: Just an addition: instead of package-lock.json, there can be a file named npm-shrinkwrap.json. Steps are the same.

Comment: I tried it both ways, I'm pretty sure it requires elevated permissions. Thanks!